# How to create Global Administrator user using Azure Active Directory B2C GraphServiceClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I would like to create a new user in Azure Active Directory B2C using the `GraphServiceClient` (the Microsoft Graph API, not the Azure AD Graph API). I have tried the following by setting `UserType = "Global Administrator"`, but this doesn't work and the `newAdminUser` shows up as a regular `User` instead of a `Global Administrator`. What am I doing wrong?

```
User newAdminUser = await graphClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(new User
{
    AccountEnabled = true,
    DisplayName = userBinding.FullName,
    MailNickname = userBinding.UserName,
    UserPrincipalName = userBinding.UserName + '@' + domain,
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        Password = new NetworkCredential(string.Empty, userBinding.Password).Password,
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true
    }
});

await graphClient.Users[newAdminUser.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(new User()
{
    UserType = "Global Administrator"
});
```

And here is a screenshot of `newAdminUser`'s Azure Active Directory B2C profile, showing that the permissions granted are not `Global Administrator`.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All users, Admin or not, is a `user` object within the directory. What access a given `user` has depends on the Directory Role they belong too.

In order to assign someone to the "Global administrator" Role, you need to add that `user` to the correct Role.

1. Find the `id` for the Role you want by retrieving a [list of `directoryRoles`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/directoryrole_list):

```cs
var directoryRoles = await graphClient.DirectoryRoles
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

2. [Add the `user`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/directoryrole_post_members) to the Role:

```cs
await graphClient.DirectoryRoles["role-id"]
    .Members
    .References
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(newAdminUser);
```